# How to solve "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException unable to find constructor to use for types" Android error?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dll, json.net

I'm working in an App with Unity3D.

Im using my own utilities DLL with some classes.

I've been working for months now, and made lots of builds/compilations with no problem.

Last week added a new class to the DLL, it worked well in my PC but when I builded the project and used it in my Android device it stopped working. The Android Monitor program shows me that error:

**"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException unable to find constructor to use for types"**

The types that Newtonsoft can find constructors for, are the new classes I added recently.

**Important**: All the other classes are deserialized with no errors.

The only different think that the new class has is the **namespace** and the **type**. Variables, methods and constructors still the same.

It is also important that the project works fine on PC, the problem only occurs in Android.

I know I can do some custom deserializers or add tags, etc.. to my class. But the thing is that only that class causes the problem and it is no reason to change the JSon deserialization system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Background:** This is a common problem that roots from the UnityLinker's bytecode stripping algorithms. What's happening is that the UnityLinker cannot see any use of your types constructor (as Newtonsoft.Json only uses it via reflection, which a compiler cannot foresee), so it removes it. This bytecode stripping is only activated when building with the IL2CPP scripting backend, which is why you didn't experience any problem when building on your PC (or any other solely using Mono for that matter).

**The fix:** To overcome this, you can disable bytecode stripping for that type (or even just for that constructor). You can do this using a `link.xml` file. Example:

```xml
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="MyAssembly">
        <type fullname="MyAssembly.MyCSharpClass">
            <!-- disables stripping just for the constructor -->
            <method signature="System.Void .ctor()"/>
        </type>

        <!-- disables stripping for the entire type -->
        <type fullname="MyAssembly.MyCSharpClass" preserve="all" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

I've written some helpful pages on using `link.xml` among other tools to cope with AOT issues, as I find Unity's documentation to be lacking and scattered:
https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Fix-AOT-using-link.xml

To read more about why this is, please refer to my explanation page: https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/What-even-is-AOT

Comment: Exactly what I needed! My team thought this issue only happened in IOS but it is a generic Newtonsoft configuration.

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned, it happens because unity code stripping on il2cpp is a bit over-eager and removes the constructor because it can't see that it's really being used.

Apart from the suggested solutions here, it's also possible to add the `UnityEngine.Scripting.PreserveAttribute` to an empty constructor. Like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine.Scripting;

[Preserve] // Ensures it survives code-stripping
public Response()
{
}
```

I think prefer this way over using link.xml, as it keeps everyting related to that class in one place, and not spread across multiple files.

Comment: don't forget to manually save the file. got bit in the ass by VS not auto-saving my code and thought this way didn't work at first!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can have an empty constructor in class in order to de-serialize it.
2. You can try putting this in your class:

   [Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]

Comment: But I still dont know the source of the problem..   1. I don't have any empty constructor in any class.   2. I don't have any tag like that anywhere.. should I just put it in that conflictive class, without knowing the real issue?

Answer (score 1):

Applejag's answer is the correct one  (link.xml or AotHelper), but I have an alternative. A lazy one. :)

Check your 'Managed Stripping Level' within Unity's player settings for iOS and for Android. Mine was set to High and when I switched to Low it resolved the issue.   Granted, there are some repercussions to file size for that, but if you are working in a small app like myself then it is not an issue.