# Unity NewtonSoft Deserialization doesn't work in Build?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net, json-deserialization

my project is working fine in play mode from Unity.
But in my Build, it is not working. I'm getting an error from my JSON deserializer:

JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type POIListCollection. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'pois', line 2, position 9.

But I have a constructor:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class POIListCollection
{
public PointOfInterest[] pois { get; set; }

[JsonConstructor]
public POIListCollection(PointOfInterest[] pois) {

    this.pois = pois;

}
/**
 *  Also tried:
 *   public POIListCollection() {
 *
 *   }
 * 
*/
}
```

I couldn't find a solution online.
So what's wrong here?
I'd be very grateful for any answers!

Edit: As requested the JSON:
[image]

And also the PointOfInterest Class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[System.Serializable]
public class PointOfInterest
{

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Color color { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Geoposition location { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string spritepath { get; set; }
    public bool isTemporal { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public bool openStatus { get; set; }
    public int openTime { get; set; }
    public int closeTime { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public double cost { get; set; }
    public double chargeSartionDistance { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }

    public PointOfInterest (string name, string category, string spritepath, bool isTemporal, double lat, double lon, bool openStatus, double rating, string[] tags, double cost, double chargeStationDistance, int closeTime, int openTime) {

        this.name = name; 
        this.category = category;
        this.spritepath = spritepath;
        this.isTemporal = isTemporal;
        this.lat = lat; 
        this.lon = lon;
        this.openStatus = openStatus;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.chargeSartionDistance = chargeStationDistance;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.closeTime = closeTime;
        this.openTime = openTime;


    }



}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a default constructor, without any arguments? Since pois variable is public, you can assign the value to it immediately after the object creation.

Comment: @shtrule according to [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) the usage seems to be right though ... What is `PointOfInterest`? Maybe this one is lagging such constructor as well? Otherwise in your case you could just not have any custom constructor (=> defaults to empty parameterless constructor)

Comment: Could you show us your `PointOfInterest` and content of the JSON string? I think **if** you use `[JsonConstructor]` then the order of fields in the JSON has o match with your parameters => if in you JSON the first thing is not `pois`, an  `PointOfInterest[]` it will still fail

Comment: @derHugo As requested I added the rest of the code and the JSON. But as I said, it really works and everything is deserialized in the standard unity play mode, however, it only doesn't work if i build it. And thanks for the help!

Comment: @RezarakSL Could it be a code-stripping issue then? If your code doesn't have an explicit constructor call for a class, then its constructor might get stripped.

Check this for more info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html

Comment: Agree that code stripping might be the issue.  E.g. if using using unity3d on android, see [How to solve "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException unable to find constructor to use for types" Android error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59757635).  Try adding [`[Preserve]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PreserveAttribute.html) to your constructor as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67418226) by t9mike.

Comment: Thanks @everyone, I changed the Code stripping level to "disabled" and it works in the build now! Things like this are really hard to find out yourself because the error doesn't leave a clue as to where to start. So thanks again for the help! However just writing the [Preserve] tag before the constructor did not work for some reason.