# Newtonsoft.Json via Google OAUTH api doesn't work properly when built with WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

In my project I use google apis (specifically google sheets api v4). In using this I have to use google OAuth 2. Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.0 is a dependency of this library. Everything works fine in the editor and when I compile for pc. However when I compile with WebGL I get a plethora of errors relating to Newtonsoft.Json. Such as the following: [image]

Any suggest?

Notes:
Using a link.xml file as suggested by [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/applejag/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Fix-AOT-using-link.xml) does not solve the issue neither does the AotHelper method mentioned in that thread. Leading me to believe that the error is not related to AOT and possibly realtered to its use by Google Auth api

For newtonsoft.Json I am using [Newtonsoft.Json for Unity 13.0.1 release 2 AOT dll](https://github.com/applejag/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/releases/tag/13.0.102) although I have tried Newtonsof.Json 13.0.1 from several different sources including Unity's official package

Comment: This looks like a similar issue to what is described in [How to solve "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException unable to find constructor to use for types" Android error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59757635/how-to-solve-newtonsoft-json-jsonserializationexception-unable-to-find-construc), even if the platform isn't the same.